# Iterate through nested JSON to get specific key values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an output JSON file from an API call "ruletree" and I need to iterate through it to get values for **domainName**, **rule** & **host** keys. My ultimate goal is to put the iteration result into a new dictionary "newjson" and print in a log file called "domains".

current code

```
ruletree = result.json()

#code to get domainName, name & host
newjson =

#add date for every log line
now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
new_d = {"date_time": now, **newjson}

#save to log file
with open('/opt/logs/domains', 'a') as outfile:
  json.dump(new_d, outfile)
  print(file=outfile)
```

ruletree content

```
ruletree = {
    "contract": "1234",
    "domainName": "www.domainA.com",
    "rules": {
        "name": "default",
        "children": [
            {
                "rule": "Rule1",
                "children": [],
                "behaviors": [
                    {
                        "name": "origin",
                        "options": {
                            "originType": "CUSTOMER",
                            "host": "gateway1.com",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "rule": "Rule2",
                "children": [],
                "behaviors": [
                    {
                        "name": "origin",
                        "options": {
                            "originType": "CUSTOMER",
                            "host": "gateway2.com",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

expected output

```
{"date_time": "2023-07-06 06:67:06", "domainName": "www.domainA.com", "rule": "Rule1", "host": "gateway1.com")
{"date_time": "2023-07-06 06:67:06", "domainName": "www.domainA.com", "rule": "Rule2", "host": "gateway2.com")
{"date_time": "2023-07-06 06:67:06", "domainName": "www.domainB.com", "rule": "Rule1", "host": "gateway1.com")
{"date_time": "2023-07-06 06:67:06", "domainName": "www.domainB.com", "rule": "Rule2", "host": "gateway2.com")
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated code with minimal changes, and it also fixes the issue while writing the JSONL file. The code in question would append a list of JSON to the file, which will make the file messier and hard to read through code.

```
import datetime
import json

ruletree = {
    "contract": "1234",
    "domainName": "www.domainA.com",
    "rules": {
        "name": "default",
        "children": [
            {
                "rule": "Rule1",
                "children": [],
                "behaviors": [
                    {
                        "name": "origin",
                        "options": {
                            "originType": "CUSTOMER",
                            "host": "gateway1.com",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "rule": "Rule2",
                "children": [],
                "behaviors": [
                    {
                        "name": "origin",
                        "options": {
                            "originType": "CUSTOMER",
                            "host": "gateway2.com",
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}

data = {
    'date_time': datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    'domainName': ruletree['domainName'],
}

#code to get domainName, name & host
for rule in ruletree['rules']['children']:
    for behavior in rule['behaviors']:
        with open('domains.json', 'a+') as outfile: # writing to the file
            json.dump({
                **data,
                'rule': rule['rule'],
                'host': behavior['options']['host']
            }, outfile)
            outfile.write('\n')
```

File output:

```
{"date_time": "2023-07-11 11:28:21", "domainName": "www.domainA.com", "rule": "Rule1", "host": "gateway1.com"}
{"date_time": "2023-07-11 11:28:21", "domainName": "www.domainA.com", "rule": "Rule2", "host": "gateway2.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple generator function will do here.

```
def get_rule_data(ruletree):
    for child in ruletree["rules"]["children"]:
        rule_name = child["rule"]
        for behavior in child.get("behaviors", []):
            try:
                host = behavior["options"]["host"]
                yield ruletree["domainName"], rule_name, host
            except KeyError:
                pass


now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

for domain, rule_name, origin_domain in get_rule_data(ruletree):
    print(
        {
            "date_time": now,
            "domainName": domain,
            "rule_name": rule_name,
            "host": origin_domain,
        }
    )
```